# Android IMEI: todas versões android

Tags: java, android

s métodos abaixo não são eficazes para capturar o IMEI de todas as versões de Android.

```
private String getIMEINumber() {
        String IMEINumber = "";
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getImei(0);
            } else {
                IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
            }
        }
        return IMEINumber;
    }





public static String getUniqueIMEIId(Context context) {
        try {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return "";
            }
            String imei = telephonyManager.getImei();
            Log.e("imei", "=" + imei);
            if (imei != null && !imei.isEmpty()) {
                return imei;
            } else {
                return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "not_found";
    }
```

Comment: Bom dia, cara acho melhor você parar de usar o IMEI. O google já vem dizendo que a partir de um certo tempo eles vão tirar os aplicativos que ainda usam o IMEI. Te aconselho a usar o AdvertisingID(http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/id.html).

Comment: Obrigado João Vitor.

Answer (score 0):

Além disso, você precisa solicitar a permissão.
Dá uma olhadinha nesse código talvez te ajude.

```
// chamando a permissão do App
private  void callPermissions(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // se tudo estiver certinho
    } else {
        requestPhonePermission();
    }
}

private void requestPhonePermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permissão Necessária")
                .setMessage("Fundamentais para o funcionamento !)")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, READ_PHONE_STATE_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, READ_PHONE_STATE_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){

    if (requestCode == READ_PHONE_STATE_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissão Concedida!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // tudo certinho
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissão Necessária!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```